# CS GO: Comp game joining issues (MAC)

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, macos

I am having a problem with CS:GO on my mac. When i am invited to join a lobby a game can be found and works perfectly.

Although when i try to join a comp game by myself, it doesn't load, just keeps counting up.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, what you mean by "just keeps counting up" is the number of servers/players being searched going up constantly.
In that case, it sounds like the client just can't find a game to join. Usually if you wait for long enough, it'll find a game and join it.

However, if it always takes too long, you could check one thing: What maps are selected? If there's only a single map selected which isn't that popular, the client might not be able to find an available game. You'll just need to add in a couple of more popular maps.

If that doesn't help at all, the usual culprit is the MaxPing settings that could be preventing the client from finding an available server for you to join.
You can check the current value by opening up the console and typing these:

> mm_dedicated_server_maxping

Let's say it's 80... This means the client won't join any servers if find wich have a higher ping. So you might want to raise this by typing something like this in the console:

> mm_dedicated_server_maxping 150

You can pick the numeric value as high as you want, but keep it in mind that these numeric values are in milliseconds, so setting a value of 250 means that you'll accept playing on a server where there will be a quarter of a second lag for you.
You should keep these three settings the same:

- mm_session_search_ping
- mm_dedicated_search_maxping
- mm_dedicated_server_maxping

Note: The key to open the console depends on your keyboard layout, but it usually is the ` or ~ key right below the Escape key for the US layout, and likewise it's the ` or ¬ key in the UK layout on PC keyboards. I wouldn't know what it is on a Mac keyboard.
If the console is disabled, you'll need to enable it from the options, and that option should also display the key for the console:
[image: Enable Developer Console]