# Not able to find any match in CS:GO

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I bought CS:GO, but when I try to play online, it's just searching for matches all the time. It never finds any matches. I have been searching for 15 minutes, and still haven't found anything. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255207/cs-go-comp-game-joining-issues-mac

Comment: my best suggestion is for people who suffer from poor internet connections like myself. There is a console command that can change the maximum allowed ping that matchmaking will connect you to games with. the default is around 100 if i recall. The command should be something like "cl_maxping" or something like that, but if you cant find it, it also appears in one of the options menus too.

Answer (score 1):

The search time is heavily dependent on many things and waiting 15min is pretty normal depending on these conditions. In South Africa where I am from, it's possible to wait up to an hour for competitive games if you play during the week at certain times.

---

## Here are some of the reasons you're waiting long for matchmaking games

### Max Acceptable Matchmaking Ping

Your Max Acceptable Matchmaking Ping is set way too low. If your ping is higher than your max, then you're going to wait a long time for a game. You will eventually get a game, but it will take much longer.

[image: CSGO Max Acceptable Matchmaking Ping]

### No one is playing the game mode

Some of the game modes are completely dead in some regions and no one is playing them. If you search for Danger Zone games in South Africa, then you will wait forever and you will never find a game because no one in South Africa plays Danger Zone. So you need a VPN in order to search for Danger Zone games in South Africa or set your max ping very high and just wait a couple of hours.

### No Local Servers

If your region doesn't have any local servers, then you could also wait a while before getting a game instead of instantly getting a game. Not every country in the world has local servers.

Answer (score -2):

Did you block anything on your firewall ?

What do you mean by it can't find ? Is it in Matchmaking ?

Also, please do try to check community servers and connect to one, maybe the issue comes from valvE.

You could also try to check game file integrety.